# Bootstrap panel layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi there i am trying to make a pannel in bootstrap. I am new to this so sorry if this is a simple question. I am trying to create a pannel like this website : [Website](https://juicerecipes.com/recipes/?color=green)

So far i have made the header , body and footer , however i cant create the body part of it, i am stuggling to create it and everything i try is not working. If anyone can assist me in this and explain it would be great help

Code so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
     <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help guys xx

Edit: Sorry i should have made it clear. The problem i am having is creating the content in the body part. So creating anther pannel for the image, then the button and then the list of ingredients. This is my main problem

Comment: I cannot understand your problem, here is what you get: https://jsfiddle.net/1zct176v/

Comment: Iam just trying to recreate the website exmaple, However i cant make the body part work , so i cant get there to be anther pannel in the body with the list of ingredients etc

Comment: If you are using Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari right click mouse inspect element and see what classes and styles are applied to elements. Also it is good to read Bootstrap documentation. It is great and you can learn a lot. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1zct176v/2/

Comment: @makshh i have tried this , however i am not an expert in this feild so i am struggling to understand this

Comment: If someone write code for you, you will also not understand.

Comment: @silviagreen that is perfect. The main problem i have had was with the body, thank you very much

Comment: @makshh its not about me just copying and pasting the cod my friend, i would like to see how someone has done it and then i can play around with it my self, this is how i work and this is how i understand the problem. Obv if i knew what i was doing i would not come on here and ask for help but thankfully silviagreen has helped me out and now i can go and play with it and understand how he has done it

Comment: OK, I just recommended to you Bootstrap documentation and Developer Tools. In Chrome Developer Tools it is very easy to determine which code represents particular element. You can learn it in 10 minutes on YouTube, but I'm not forcing you to do that :) This way you can see how someone done it, you can even copy the code from website, paste it to your site, copy styles and play with this.

Comment: @makshh thank you for the help , i have just tried it and its actually very helpfully :) xx

Comment: @EagleBlind Bootstrap documentation is really a good start point to understand hiw the grid model and the panel work. In addiction, to play with code I use Firefox developer edition browser (but Chrome Developers tools is really usefull too). In particular, use the Element inspector to find the html and css code to replicate; it is also an excellent tool to resolve and understand problems

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to nest them as needed, so this should work.

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Panel Heading</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">inner Panel Heading</div>
          <div class="panel-body">innner panel body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">inner Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">inner Panel Heading</div>
          <div class="panel-body">innner panel body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">inner Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVNmxb) of the layout